# Wider element as a child (css)

Tags: html, css

How to make it as it is in the picture?

[image: red and yellow blocks]

I have a problem with center red block.

```
.menu_ul > li{
    position:relative;
}

.menu_ul > li> ul{
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: no need to center, use negative value for left and right and make them the same

Comment: I want it to be responsive

Answer (score 0):

You can use `top:100%` to align the absolute positioned right below the relative positioned and then center it using `left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%,0);`

```css
* {
  text-align: center;
  color:white;
}
.rel {
  position: relative;
  background: brown;
  margin: 0 200px;
  padding: 25px 50px;
}

.abs {
  position:absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  background: red;
  padding: 50px 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="rel">
  relative
  <div class="abs">
    absolute
  </div>
</div>
```